# Custom elements good for markup only?

Tags: html, markup, custom-element

To create custom components, we can use custom elements. Even if we like me don't use custom components, custom elements can be used anyway, as markup. I use [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) at the moment.

**Instead of this:**

```html
<div class="row>
```

**I could use this:**

```html
<t-row>
```

It's a bit shorter and with a big template, it would save quite a bit of code size.

**I have a few questions about this approach:**

- Which will perform better in general? A div or custom element? How much does the number characters matter? I have a large table with maybe 1000 of elements on the screen at the same time. A small performance on one element may have a big impact.
- Is it a good practice to use custom elements when custom components are not bound to them?
- In Vue we can add `ignoredElements` to ignore elements like `[/^t-/]`. How will that affect performance?

All this boils down to a single question...

**Should I use custom elements as markup if I feel it could save me time and improve readability? Explain why.**

Comment: Custom element carry no inherent styling or semantic meaning. For the accessibility of all users, you should only use custom elements if you're programmatically adding those semantics. Always use semantic HTML elements whenever possible.

Comment: @sean Semantically it would make sense to simply use `tr` in this case and override it but it feels kind of wrong because I use a grid but visually, it's a table. You would use a `div`?

Comment: It depends on the contents of the element. It could be a `tr`, `div`, `li`, `section`, `article` ,  `figure`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer to question #2, arguments why **not** to do it:

#### GZip

You have to take GZip into account

Yes `<div class="row">` is more to type
but might actually create a smaller file delivered to the browser
because you used it so much **and GZip encoded that 17 bytes to a few BITS**.

#### Good code

IMHO a developer should think about delivering the best code to his/her successor,
not about optimization he/she is the only one to understand.

The first response  to `<t-row>` will be *What the Fuk is going on here*
not *Oh this is readable*.

#### Namespace

Another IMHO

Do not use `t-` just because you want to create a custom element,

namespaces should have meaning.